# How to send json object in swift without "key - value" pair format

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, alamofire

Hey so I have to send a a token string to the Django-server and it only accepts one string. I am trying to use alamo fire to do this, however I cant send a key-value pair to resolve this problem. Is there an alternative solution for this. I am new IOS developer and this is my first project and I am new to the community. Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need to send to the Django-server? From the sounds of it, it isn't really json that you're trying to send, unless it's url-encoded or something like that...

Comment: I need to send a token to the server, something like "189E23FL2".

Answer (score 0):

Convert your dictionary into a JSON string and ship it off that way:

```
func jsonStringify(data: AnyObject) -> NSData? {
    var error: NSError?

    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
        data,
        options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
        error: &error
        ) {
            return json
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *how* you need to send the token (POST vs GET vs HTTP Body vs Query String)... you might need to change the below. But it should get you started with `NSURLSession`. This will send the token `189E23FL2` to the server with POST as a HTTP Body parameter.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://some-server/endpoint")

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = "189E23FL2".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// if you need a csrf token, add something like this as well:
// request.addValue("the-csrf-token", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-CSRFToken")

var sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
var session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError!) -> Void     in

    if (error == nil) {
        println("Done!")
    } else {
        println("Errorororororor")
    }
})

// start the task
task.resume()
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the following message from my server: "detail" : "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." Using the fields on the actual server website, as well as Postman, if I send the token in the following format -> "token", it successfully logs me out. I am not sure why it does not accept what you have written, which seems the most logical to me.

Comment: The CSRF error is about cross-site-request-forgery. Since using the website directly, it is on the same _origin_ it won't complain. But within the iOS app you'll have to send a CSRF token as well. Something like: request.addValue("the-csrf-token", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-CSRFToken")